# Subscripts and superscripts in body of gt table R

Tags: r, subscript, superscript, gt

How do I get my gt table in R to show subscripts/superscripts?  I would like the numbers in the isotope column to display as superscripts.

```
library(gt)  

Isotope <- c("1H", "2H", "16O", "17O", "18O")
Abundance <- c(0.99985, 0.00015, 0.99757, 0.00038, 0.00205)
table <- as.data.frame(cbind(Isotope, Abundance))
table %>% gt()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to make use of `gt::text_transform` and the HTML `<sup>` tag like so:

```
library(gt)  
library(stringr)

Isotope <- c("1H", "2H", "16O", "17O", "18O")
Abundance <- c(0.99985, 0.00015, 0.99757, 0.00038, 0.00205)
table <- data.frame(Isotope, Abundance)
table %>% gt() %>% 
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(Isotope)
    ),
    fn = function(x){
      sup <- str_extract(x, "^\\d+")
      text <- str_extract(x, "[^\\d]+")
      glue::glue("<sup>{sup}</sup>{text}")
    }
  )
```

[image]