# With the r gt package how can I print a simple superscript in the body of a table

Tags: r, gt

I would like to include a superscript in one cell of a table printed with the `gt` package. I found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239911/subscripts-and-superscripts-in-body-of-gt-table-r) that shows how to print superscripts as part of a more complicated workflow but I just need a single superscript.  Is there an easy way to print R with a superscript 2 in the table created here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(gt)


`table3-2` <- tribble(
  ~Quantity, ~Value,
  "Residual standard error", 3.26,
  "R2", 0.612,
  "F-statistic", 312.1
)

`table3-2` %>% 
  gt()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to supply a `rows` argument to `text_transform`:

```
`table3-2` %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  text_transform(
    locations = cells_body(
      columns = c(Quantity),
      rows = 2
    ),
    fn = function(x){
      sup <- 1
      text <- "R2"
      glue::glue("<sup>{sup}</sup>{text}")
    }
  )
```

This adds a superscript to `R2` and gives us:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Easiest solution is to use the unicode values, if one exists. For the squared symbol it's "\U00B2":

```
 `table3-2` <- tribble(
  ~Quantity, ~Value,
  "Residual standard error", 3.26,
  "R\U00B2", 0.612,
  "F-statistic", 312.1
)
```

[image]